# Not able to delete user in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle11g

I am getting the error while deleting user from oracle db. The error message is not very helpful to diagnose this issue. Please let me know if you are aware of this issue.

```
SQL> drop user sshil_lrg_2 cascade;
drop user sshil_lrg_2 cascade
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 36
```

Comment: This seems relavant: https://community.oracle.com/message/9507589#9507589 (trigger getting in the way)

Answer (score 1):

The problem in most Oracle installations is a missing system table.
Oracle attempts to drop a non-existent system table during the CASCADE operation of dropping all of the user's objects.

SOLUTION:

Create the missing table in the Oracle instance.

See: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1048567?tstart=0

Then attempt the DROP USER {name} CASCADE command again.

*Was able to successfully reproduce this error in a plain-vanilla Oracle install with no specific triggers created. This solution resolved the problem.*

Comment: Yes, that is also a possible cause. It is something at recursive level 1 so something triggered indirectly. The trace may contain more.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist` indicates that some software tries to execute something like `drop table I_DO_NOT_EXIST`. However, you are not dropping a table but a user.

Looking better at the error message, you will also see `ORA-00604` and `line 36`. This is indication that your original SQL statement caused other SQL (ORA-00604) and PL/SQL (line 36) to be triggered.

Probably you have a database trigger that executes on DDL statements. Check the contents of user_triggers of the user `sys` and disable/debug these trigger.

Writing a good trigger that fires on DDL is non-trivial, since you need to ensure that you don't lock yourself out ever.

Comment: @user2032118 hi did this help solve your problem? If not please add what was not successful to your question.

Comment: The OP used a DROP USER {name} CASCADE command. This attempts to delete all of the user's objects. The error is caused by a missing table(s) associated with the Oracle instance. This is (IMHO) an Oracle bug since this can be reproduced with a plain-vanilla install and no (operator) triggers created. See: https://community.oracle.com/thread/1048567?tstart=0